# cancan - "can :manage, all". I haven't been able to get access to all in rails 3 app with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I am using "check authorization" in the application controller so every action will require a permission. I'm starting with giving me, the superadmin :=], permissions to manage all. I thought manage all would give me access to the whole app without naming a resource.

user model:

```
  def role?(role)
    roles.include? role.to_s
  end
```

application controller:

```
check_authorization
```

cancan's ability model:

```
  def initialize(user)
    if user.role? :superadmin
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
```

error message:

```
This action failed the check_authorization because it does not authorize_resource. Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Add to the class level context of controller: load_and_authorize_resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you're going to need to call `authorize_resource` in your controller as a before filter so that this works.

Comment: I thought that placing "check_authorization" in the application controller negated the need for that... but i am going to give this a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @Jay :all means every action in your controller... https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

Comment: @Hosemeyer, thanks for your reference. I may be wrong, but the way i read it, it seems to mean every action in every controller.

Comment: @Jay it does, are you "load_and_authorize_resource" in each controller?